# Breezejs unit test with jasmine karma angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, breeze, karma-jasmine

I'm building an app based in Breeze and Angular

They work pretty well together but the unit test is a problem.

This is a pretty vanilla test but Breeze keeps getting in the middle:

```
describe('myController', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        module('app');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.whenGET().respond(200, 
            {"someStrings": ["foo", "bar"]})

        //more uninteresting code...

        createController = function () {
            return $controller('myController', { '$scope': $rootScope });
        };
    }));

    it('should fetch authentication token', function () {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth.py');
        var controller = createController();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
```

The problem is that Breeze keeps being initialized. At execution, I receive the following message:

```
Error: cannot execute _executeQueryCore until metadataStore is populated.

//or,with different get: ... $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py') 
//                                 .respond({ userId: 'userX' });

Error: Unexpected request: GET breeze/Breeze/Metadata No more request expected
```

How do I prevent or mock or stub Breeze so doesn't interfere with my tests... For instance, these tests are aimed to authentication, not data.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze is not "*getting in the middle*" on its own. Breeze would not get involved in your `$http` authorization call. I'll eat my hat if you can show me that it does. You haven't shown that it does here.

But you have surfaced a very interesting point about application bootstrap design and the consequences of that design for testing.

Evidently, either your `app` module's start method or your controller's creation logic executes a Breeze query (perhaps both of them do).  I deduce this from two facts:

1. The exception comes from `executeQueryCore` which only happens when you explicitly execute a Breeze query
2. You don't touch the controller in your test, neither in the `beforeEach` nor in the `it` which means these calls (and your auth call too) are made by some kind of automatic startup logic that executes before your `it` spec.

In your test you have taken the trouble to mock the auth call (which is in your startup logic somewhere) but not the Breeze calls.

I don't know what you actually want to test. Why would you test that the controller fetches an auth token? Is that really the controller's concern?

Perhaps you present this test merely to illustrate the problems you're having testing a controller without getting the real server involved?

Let me step back and make a more important and more general point. We must be wary of automatic startup logic whether it hides in an app module `start` or a controller's constructor. Be wary in particular of startup logic that involves calls to the server.

I tend to disable automated startup logic in *most* of my tests. I often substitute test doubles for the troublesome dependent services during my test module setup ... before calling ngMock's `inject` function. I make sure that the `app.start` method's callback ONLY uses dependent services that are easy to fake.

I you want to forge ahead using the actual dependencies by mocking the HTTP responses with `$httpBackend`, then you'll have to prepare `$httpBackend` for **every request it receives** from the startup code ... including the **requests YOU are making with Breeze**.

I'll end by reiterating that *Breeze only does what you tell it to do*. It is completely unaware of your direct-to-`$http` calls.